# android :displaying user current location and the other users near to current location on android map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an android app, I've requirement to show the user current location and the other uses 
Near to current location on google map. To get the users nearby current location there is separate service i need to pass user current location lat/long only,

My Question is how I can get the user current location and display on the map (like iphone does with some animation)
All other users near  to current location (each user has a type, depending on the type i need to show different mark/drawable on the map)

Any idea or any tutorial link sample code will help me

Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need a mapview:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

Displaying the other users:

```
List<GeoPoint> otherUsers = .... from your service
for(GeoPoint user: otherUsers )
{
     mapView .addOverlay(new MapOverlay(user);
}
```

Centering the map around the user:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
//or if you want to use gps l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
//you may want to use a different manner of getting the location since this may be out of date. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html for live data
point = new GeoPoint((int)(l.getLatitude()*1e6),(int)(l.getLongitude()*1e6));
mc.animateTo(point);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Overlay class needed to show the other users:

```
public class MapOverlay extends Overlay {

    private GeoPoint data;  

    public MapLineOverlay( GeoPoint item) {
        data = item;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see com.google.android.maps.Overlay#draw(android.graphics.Canvas, com.google.android.maps.MapView, boolean, long)
    */
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,long when) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        if (shadow == false) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            Point point = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(data, point);
            paint.setColor(color);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
            canvas.drawPoint((float) point.x, (float) point.y, , paint);
            }
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see com.google.android.maps.Overlay#draw(android.graphics.Canvas, com.google.android.maps.MapView, boolean)
    */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }       
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code,just one question how can i get the current location and display it on map with some animation

Comment: I modified my answer to include that as well.